# How long will it take for Starman to get to Mars?

Tags: spacex, mars, falcon-heavy, time, tesla-roadster

How long will it take for the Starman to get to Mars? I'm following the incredible launch of the Heavy Falcon and Starman, and would like to know. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think SpaceX has said for sure, but some observers are speculating that there will be a Mars flyby in October of this year. Because the upper stage of Falcon Heavy isn't able to operate for very long, it won't be able to make the midcourse corrections needed to precisely target Mars, so the flyby may not be very close at all. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=md0K_eRSHAE&feature=youtu.be

Comment: I thought the answer was: never. Achieved a solar orbit with aphelion beyond the Orbit of Mars, perihelion close to Earth orbit, so Mars crossing, not necessarily Mars approaching.

Answer (score 8):

Don't know how specific you want, but at 7:59 AM - 6 Feb 2018 [Elon tweeted](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/960905835118505984?s=17)

> About 2.5 hours to T-0 for Falcon Heavy. Watch sim for highlight reel of what we hope happens. Car actually takes 6 months to cover 200M+ miles to Mars

---

<sub>Edit: A clarifying note that we just learned as well.  Again [according to Elon on 7 Feb. 2018](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/961083704230674438):</sub>

> Third burn successful. Exceeded Mars orbit and kept going to the Asteroid Belt. [Image of expected orbit](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DVZ0h3YW4AIc-9w.jpg:large)

Answer (score 1):

It won't ever really get to Mars, but it will be pretty close in 2020, and even closer in 2035. I did a video linked below that shows this.